# I want to see Linux terminal command 'size' source code

Tags: linux

Linux has many utils: coreutils, textutils, fileutils and sh-utils.

I found many util source code. for example, 'ls', 'cat', etc.

However I can't find **'size'.**

Where can I find 'size' command source code?

[image: linux size command]

Comment: visit this :`http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size`, as with most programs for examining and manipulating code files, is in [**binutils**](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).